# How to access SYS database of Hive in Spark using Java?

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I tried executing this:

*spark.sql(“select * from sys.sds limit 10”).show(10,false)*

but got below error:

21/01/04 05:25:35 ERROR log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcSerDe not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcSerDe not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2501)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(HiveMetaStoreUtils.java:84)
ueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:642)....

Comment: I hive you need to add jar with org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcSerDe to be able to query table based on JdbcSerDe

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did add below jars:
1. hive-jdbc-handler-2.3.0
2. hive-jdbc-handler-2.3.4
2. hive-jdbc-handler-3.1.2
But getting the same error: - 
error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcSerDe not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.storage.jdbc.JdbcSerDe not found at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2501) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer...

Comment: Does it fail in pure Hive also or only on Spark?

Comment: This query actually works in Hive but not in Spark - 
spark.sql(“select * from sys.sds limit 10”).show(10,false)